# 3.3 V Arduino Pro Mini and nRF24L01 issues

Tags: nrf24l01+

I have a 3.3 V Pro Mini connected to nRF24l01 as xmtr. The nRF24L01 does not respond to the Pro Mini. Any help will be appreciated.

I have attached the print detail output:

```
Transmitter 2  Started
STATUS       = 0xff RX_DR=1 TX_DS=1 MAX_RT=1 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=1
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0xffffffffff 0xffffffffff
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff
TX_ADDR      = 0xffffffffff
RX_PW_P0-6   = 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff
EN_AA        = 0xff
EN_RXADDR    = 0xff
RF_CH        = 0xff
RF_SETUP     = 0xff
CONFIG       = 0xff
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0xff 0xff
Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01
CRC Length   = 16 bits
PA Power     = PA_MAX

Transmitter 2 Started
STATUS       = 0x0e RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=0
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0xe8e8f0f0e2 0xc2c2c2c2c2
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0xc3 0xc4 0xc5 0xc6
TX_ADDR      = 0xe8e8f0f0e2
RX_PW_P0-6   = 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
EN_AA        = 0x3f
EN_RXADDR    = 0x03
RF_CH        = 0x73
RF_SETUP     = 0x07
CONFIG       = 0x0e
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0x03 0x06
Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01+
CRC Length   = 16 bits
PA Power     = PA_MAX
voltage = 3.97 V
0
RSLT (1 = success) 0
Data Sent 3.00  0.00  3.97
voltage = 3.85 V
voltage = 3.79 V
voltage = 3.75 V
voltage = 3.73 V
0
RSLT (1 = success) 0
Data Sent 3.00  0.00  3.73
voltage = 3.70 V
voltage = 3.68 V
voltage = 3.65 V
voltage = 3.62 V
0
RSLT (1 = success) 0
Data Sent 3.00  0.00  3.62
voltage = 3.58 V
voltage = 3.54 V
voltage = 3.50 V
voltage = 3.45 V
0
```

The top transmitter output is before I changed the nRF24L01 module which appeared to be bad.
The second transmitter started output. Module is good but nRF24L01 would not connect to receiver with 3.3 V Pro Mini. It connects if I use a Nano.

Comment: Transmitter 2 is not connected properly. Unwire and rewire it.

Answer (score 1):

> voltage = 3.97 V 0 RSLT (1 = success) 0 Data Sent 3.00 0.00

nrf24l01 is a 3.3V device, Where'd that come from?

Answer (score 0):

LM317T set to 3.25 Volts and 220uF tantalum on the nrf24L01.

Pro mini and nrf24L01 powered by 3.25V works a treat. :-)

Problem with arduino nano is that the USB from laptop is 5V and that is a killer for the nrf24L01!
If using serial.write to send data to a serial monitor through the nano's USB insure that the power and levels are not 5V on the nrf24L01.

Answer (score -1):

Promini 3.3V regulator is also only good for 150mA. I think the nrf24L01 needs more current than that.

Comment: Only the high-power version needs more current. What matters is stable voltage but this guy has wiring issues.